# C++ while loop reading ifstream, wont stop at eof

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read a file with ifstream:

```
std::ifstream is("sample_freeway.h264", std::ifstream::binary);

std::cout << "reading" << std::endl;
if (is)
{
    while (!is.eof() || !is.fail() || !is.bad())
    {
        auto buffer = std::make_shared<SimpleEncodedPacket>();
        is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(buffer->getFramePointer()), buffer->getSize());
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "could not open file" << std::endl;
}
```

but the `while` keeps going forever, even though the file is super small. It should finish almost instantly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `while` loop will run so long as at least **one** of the conditions is met. You probably mean `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: Please take some to read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: Adrian Mole has it right. De Morgans law is your friend: ``!(a | b | c) == !a && !b && !c``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
while (!is.eof() || !is.fail() || !is.bad())
```

to

```
while (!is.eof() && !is.fail() && !is.bad())
```

as said Adrian Mole.

Or even better, use `is.good()` (thanks BitTickler)

Answer (score 2):

As Adrian Mole pointed out, you got the boolean expression wrong. But this is actually so common, that there is another "goodie" hidden in std::ios:

See for example [the reference on cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/):

> std::ios::good
> bool good() const;
> Check whether state of stream is good
> Returns true if none of the stream's error state flags (eofbit, failbit and badbit) is set.

Had you used this function, you would not have been able to make the mistake you made.

```
    ...
    while( is.good() ) {
        ...
    }
    ...
```